# WebForms site sample

Tags: jquery, asp.net, unit-testing, entity-framework, ioc-container

What I'm looking for is a good sample of an open source WebForms site which contains demonstrations of some best practices, design patterns etc. Just want too look how experienced people apply their knowledge to build websites which can be shown to everybody without shame :)

It would be good if the samples show these technologies: IoC, Entity Framework, Unit testing (with mocks), jQuery.

The small samples which demonstrate the particular technology are useless as I've already examined many of them.

My goal it to improve the existing huge WinForms application, so I'm not interested in ASP.NET MVC for the time being.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are improving a WinForms application, why are you asking about web technologies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [a list](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/388/aspnet-open-source-projects/) of some of the popular open source asp.net projects.